# Replace substring

Tags: string

Is there any way to replace a string with a char ?

Example :

I have,

```
123456789
```

And, I want to replace all chars from position 3 to position 8 with * , to produce this result

```
12******9
```

Is there a way perhaps using

```
sed -i "s/${mystring:3:5}/*/g" ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign a variable `var1=123456789`

`echo $var1` will give `123456789`

then `var2="${var1:0:2}*****${var1:8:9}"`

`echo $var2` will give `12*****9`

Comment: Sorry , i was unexplicit , from position 3 of the string, i meant to say

Comment: ok I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where the data is. If it is in a shell variable then

Construct a new string with the first two characters from the original, the substituted string and the trailing characters of the original. Either assign it back to the original or use it as a variable. Decide if you want to check if the original string is shorter than 8 characters.

```
mystring="${mystring:0:2}******${mystring:8}"
```

You could do

```
mystring=${mystring/????????/${mystring{0:2}******}
```

If it is in a file then

```
sed 's/\(..\)......../\1********/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track.

If you want to use `sed` then,

- pipe your string into sed.
- remove `-i` flag
- remove `g` suffix you are only substituting one string ie `45678`
- add apropriate number of character to the substitution string, ie `*****`

  echo ${mystring}|sed "s/${mystring:3:5}/*****/g"